# C++ - Parentheses after variable name in declaration

Tags: c++, arduino, variable-declaration

I'm looking at [some Arduino code](https://gist.github.com/kriegsman/1f7ccbbfa492a73c015e) and encountering a construct I haven't seen before:

`CRGBPalette16 currentPalette( CRGB::Black );`

`CRGB::Black` is a constant, which, as some have pointed out is a number.

Later on in the code the author appears to write directly to `currentPalette` (or other similar variables) like this: `currentPalette[12] = CRGB::Black;`

Is currentPalette an object instance? If so then how can you access it as if it were an array?

Comment: It is not valid C. It *could be* C++, though.

Comment: It _could_ be a macro in C as well. EDIT: No, it cannot.

 But, having looked at the rest of the code, I do believe it is indeed C++.

Comment: Are you sure `CRGB::Black` is actually a struct and not an enum constant?

Comment: @wildplasser: It is *Arduino Language*, which is an unspecified, undocumented (basically "whatever the Arduino IDE will accept") close relative of C++. The actual compiler is a fork of GCC, but the IDE does some preprocessing and wrapping of the code (for example generating a suitable `main` method).

Comment: `CRGB::Black` is a number, not a struct. There are many constructors for `CRGBPalette16`, with varying numbers of parameters. Related: [FastLED reference](http://fastled.io/docs/3.1/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having had a look at [the rest of the file](https://gist.github.com/kriegsman/1f7ccbbfa492a73c015e), I believe you are looking at some `C++` code.

`CRGBPalette16 currentPalette( CRGB::Black );`

This line *initialises an object of type `CRGBPalette16`* with the enum parameter `CRGB::Black`.

You can see the object passed as a reference into other functions, such as here on line 72:

`leds[i] = ColorFromPalette( currentPalette, colorIndex + sin8(i*16), brightness);`

Comment: Thanks. So CRGBPalette16 is an object and we're calling its constructor here? It's weird, because you can assign directly to it like: `currentPalette[12] = 0xffcc88;`

Comment: Not weird at all because you can define an overload operator for objects. Have a look at https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/98-overloading-the-subscript-operator/

Comment: EDIT: Just realised my mistake there in my last comment. It should say "You can define an overload to the subscript operator for objects".